# jqueryUI sortable: how to force update of placeholder position while dragging

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

When a jQueryUI sortable list is in the middle of a dragging operation, is there a way to force jQuery to update the position of the placeholder, even if the user is only moving the mouse horizontally?  (jQuery's hit-testing for a vertical sortable seems only to work when the mouse moves vertically too.)

Undocumented or hacky solutions that involve monkeying around with the internals of the sortable, draggable, etc. are OK as a last resort if a documented solution isn't available.

Here's more info:

If you drag an item onto the right side of a vertical jQueryUI sortable list, unless you move the mouse up or down the list doesn't sort. Once you move the mouse up or down (even just 1px!) suddenly the list sorts.  Example is at http://jsfiddle.net/f3Lhg/ and excerpted below.

This may seem like a corner case but it's actually common when connected lists drag sideways from one list to the other. Even if an entire drag isn't perfectly horizontal, the first 30px-100px might be, leading to unpredictable dragging behavior and lousy user experience. Even though the problem happens more with connected lists, you can easily repro with a single list by dragging out of the list and coming back into the list from the side.

The problem is not browser-specific. Behavior was identical on all browsers I tested with. Also, adding the `tolerance` option doesn't solve the problem.

Is this a jQueryUI bug or expected behavior?  And are there known workarounds?

BTW, in my app I have connected lists to the right so I can't use the `{axis:'y'}` option because that will prevent dragging to the connected lists.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .sortable { list-style-type: none; width: 400px; }
    .sortable li { margin: 5px 0; padding: 30px; border: 1px solid #999; }
    .sortable li.placeholder { margin: 0; height: 4px; border: 0; padding: 0; background-color: #800; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.sortable').sortable({
                placeholder: 'placeholder'
            }).disableSelection();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="sortable">
        <li>Item #1</li>
        <li>Item #2</li>
        <li>Item #3</li>
        <li>Item #4</li>
        <li>Item #5</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the jQuery UI [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.sortable.js) this appears to be expected behavior.

Based on how the `axis` property value is set (or not), jQuery UI sets a property `floating` as a boolean flag to track whether your container is a vertical or horizontal list (line 46):

```
//Let's determine if the items are being displayed horizontally
this.floating = this.items.length ? o.axis === 'x' || (/left|right/).test(this.items[0].item.css('float')) || (/inline|table-cell/).test(this.items[0].item.css('display')) : false;
```

This value is used to determine how jQuery UI handles collision detection while the user is dragging an element.

**Specifically:**

The method `_intersectsWithSides` (line 492) uses the property `floating` to determine that you are not dragging in a horizontal list and so returns the vertical collision results.  The vertical collision check only returns true if there is both a *vertical drag direction* and an intersection of elements:

```
if (this.floating && horizontalDirection) {
    return ((horizontalDirection == "right" && isOverRightHalf) || (horizontalDirection == "left" && !isOverRightHalf));
} else {
    return verticalDirection && ((verticalDirection == "down" && isOverBottomHalf) || (verticalDirection == "up" && !isOverBottomHalf));
}
```

It may be possible to resolve your issue by removing the `verticalDirection`  requirement from the return conditional in `_intersectsWithSides` (it might also cause unanticipated buggy behaviors).

Alternatively:

You can try editing the plugin's `_intersectsWithSides` method to return true if there is either a vertical OR horizontal drag:

```
return (verticalDirection || horizontalDirection) && ((verticalDirection == "down" && isOverBottomHalf) || (verticalDirection == "up" && !isOverBottomHalf)) || ((horizontalDirection == "right" && isOverRightHalf) || (horizontalDirection == "left" && !isOverRightHalf));
```

Comment: Nice, this is helpful. Do you know if there a method to specifically force the placeholder position to be recalculated?

Comment: @JustinGrant: `.sortable('refreshPositions')` will force the positions to be recalculated, but that won't give you your desired result.  It will run the check, decide there is no overlap because there has been no vertical mouse drag, and reposition as if your draggable wasn't there (no change).

To achieve what you want you'd have to edit your jQuery UI source code to remove the `verticalDirection` check in the collision reporting function `_intersectsWithSides`.

I don't know if doing that will cause unwanted behavior changes in the plugin.  You'll have to decide if that's a sound approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, Maybe I have misread something here.

Are you saying the problem is that if you grab the first list item drag it all the way to the right, out of the list and then drag it to item#4 it doesn't choose the relevant finishing position until you move the cursor at least 1px up or down?

Cause if so I really don't think it is a serious useability problem at all. I replicated the example as i described above and it required me to be VERY careful in order to move the mouse perfectly horizontally.

Plus I think the instinct of all users will be to drag the items and move them vertically instead of horizontally anyway.

Comment: Yep, correct. this isn't a deal-breaker problem, but it does mean that drag operations will be "jumpy", meaning the placeholder starts out in one location far removed from where the user's mouse is and then suddenly jumps to a nearby location once the user moves vertically. Even if it's just for 50px of horizontal movement it's still awkward. It's not a huge problem but it seems like it should be easy to fix with a simple call to "update placholder" in response to a hover() handler on the element, but I don't know how to update the placholder. ;-)